# Wireshark Display Filter protocol==TLSV1? (and PacketLength)

Tags: wireshark, filtering

What would the filter expression be to just select the protocols where the protocol = TLSV1? 
Something obvious like protocol == "TLSV1" or TCP.protocol == "TLSV1" is apparently not the right way.

ip.proto == "TLSV1" says "ip.proto cannot accept strings as values"

**Update - additional tips:**

Another great but hidden search is on PacketLength: 
You can add packet length to your display by clicking "Edit Preferences" (menu or icon), and adding the PacketLength as a new column, but to filter on it you have to use the more cryptic: frame.len == ### where ### is your desired number.  We were using this to determine how many packets had been sent and/or received, when you filter, the status-bar at the bottom of the screen shows the number of items matching the filter.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ssl.record.version == 0x0301

That tells Wireshark to only display packets that are SSL conversations using TLS semantics.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Seems like one could filter on the words on the screen instead of the crypto codes.

Comment: "ip.proto == 6"was somewhat close to what I wanted (but gives SMB and TCP as well as TLSV1)

Comment: "ip.proto" refers to the "Protocol" field in the IP header: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/i/ip.html. "ip.proto == 6" means "Any TCP packet carried over IPv4". Most of Wireshark's display filters correspond to a numeric value in a given protocol header.

Comment: @Gerald is right. IP Protocol Number is nothing like TCP Port number, which is why it said "ip.proto cannot accept strings."  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers

Comment: FYI : Version Values            dec     hex
 -------------------------------------
 SSL 3.0                   3,0  0x0300
 TLS 1.0                   3,1  0x0301
 TLS 1.1                   3,2  0x0302
 TLS 1.2                   3,3  0x0303

Comment: source : http://blog.fourthbit.com/2014/12/23/traffic-analysis-of-an-ssl-slash-tls-session

Comment: I think this answer should really be `ssl.handshake.version` instead of `ssl.record.version`. There's a difference between the TLS Record and TLS Handshake layers